# Why Spring Boot actuator logger end-point did not work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am  using Spring Boot 3.2.2 , JDK 21, Maven. File `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>vy</groupId>
    <artifactId>certificate_spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>certificate_spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

File `application.properties`

```java
logging.level.root=INFO
```

File `CertificateSpringApplication.java`

```java
package vy.certificate_spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CertificateSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CertificateSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

File `FooController.java`

```java
package vy.certificate_spring.account.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping("/bar")
    public String bar(){
        return "bar";
    }

}
```

The reference document at here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#loggers.all said go to http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers , but I see it did not work.

[image]

[image]

Why Spring Boot actuator logger end-point did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define which endpoints are exposed using the following property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include`. You can add all endpoints using

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing

Comment: Do you know how to expose logging of package `account.web` only, and what is its path?